# How to replace the pattern with calling external command with vim :global command

Tags: vim

For example, I have a file with file paths, one per line. I want to prepend a letter 'L' before all paths that are symbolic links.

One way I can think of is using [`:global`](https://learnvim.irian.to/basics/the_global_command) command (or `:g` for short), in form of `:g/.../normal IL`. However, the `:g` command expects a pattern at position denoted by `...`, while being a symbolic link path is not a pattern.

One the other hand, with Perl one-liner,

```perl
perl -ne 'chomp; exit 1 if -l' <<< '/path/to/symlink'
```

the snippet returns 1 when stdin contains a symbolic link path.

The overall picture I'm thinking about is to somehow invoke the perl snippet at the ellipsis position, and do `normal IL` for each line where the perl command returns non-zero.

Is it possible to achieve my goal?
Note that I'm aware of the solution to filter the input with external command. For the above-mentioned scenario, the command could be: `:%!perl -pe 'chomp($f = $_); s/^/L/ if -l $f'`. But I find it difficult to generalize to other editing action (e.g. deleting) while maintaining the line filtering criterion. Please also do not limit to perl -- the external command can be anything; perl is used here only for illustrative purpose.

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I would do it, with `:help :global`:

```
:g/^/s/.*/\=submatch(0)->resolve()!=submatch(0)?'L'..submatch(0):submatch(0)
```

1. The pattern given to `:help :global` is `^`, which matches on every line.
2. The command is a substitution where the pattern matches the whole line.
3. And the replacement is an expression that returns the whole match prepended with a `L` if it is a symlink or the untouched whole match if it is not.

I used built-in functions, which are more portable, but you could definitely use an external command instead:

```
:g/^/s/.*/\=system('cmd', submatch(0))->trim()?'L'..submatch(0):submatch(0)
```

See `:help sub-replace-special`, `:help submatch()`, `:help system()`, `:help trim()`.

FWIW, `:global`'s primary purpose is to execute a given command on lines matching (or not) a given pattern. If you only have file paths in your file, a simple `:help :s` would do:

```
:%s/^.*/\=submatch(0)->resolve()!=submatch(0)?'L'..submatch(0):submatch(0)
```

or:

```
:%s/.*/\=system('cmd', submatch(0))->trim()?'L'..submatch(0):submatch(0)
```